# Break line in $ $ mode

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I have a long list of vectors written between the signs $ $, the problem is that the list is so long it does not fit the page. I want to make the list break at some point and continue in the following line, how could I do this?

THis is my script.

```
$G(B)=\left \{ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 4 & -17 & 24 \end{pmatrix}^T,\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & -3 & 3 \end{pmatrix}^T,\begin{pmatrix}1 & -4 & 14 & -21 \end{pmatrix}^T, \begin{pmatrix}2 & -4 & 11 & -18 \end{pmatrix}^T, \
\begin{pmatrix}3 & -4 & 8 & -15 \end{pmatrix}^T,\begin{pmatrix}4 & -4 & 5 & -12 \end{pmatrix}^T, \begin{pmatrix}5 & -4 & 2 & -9 \end{pmatrix}^T, \begin{pmatrix}6 & -4 & -1 & -6 \end{pmatrix}^T\right \}, 
 \begin{pmatrix}11 & -8 & 1 & -15 \end{pmatrix}^T, \begin{pmatrix}17 & -12 & 0 & -21 \end{pmatrix}^T, \begin{pmatrix}7 & -4 & -4 & -3 \end{pmatrix}^T,  \begin{pmatrix}8 & -4 & -7 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^T \right \} $
```

Thanks!

Comment: You may really want to reconsider how legible -- or, rather, how illegible -- a group of twelve [12!] four-element vectors typeset in inline math mode is. Any chance you can switch to displaymath mode?

Comment: @Werner: The question is a duplicate, but not the answers!

Comment: @Herbert: Yes. In those cases one can flag the question for moderator attention and request the answers (posts) be merged together.

Comment: @Werner: it was you, who said that the question has already an answer. But the main problem of this question  is `\left ...\right` and that is answered here!

Answer (score 3):

In this case I'd prefer an align environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent
    $G(B)=\Big\{ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 4 & -17 & 24 \end{pmatrix}^T,
            \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & -3 & 3 \end{pmatrix}^T,
            \begin{pmatrix}1 & -4 & 14 & -21 \end{pmatrix}^T, 
            \begin{pmatrix}2 & -4 & 11 & -18 \end{pmatrix}^T, \linebreak[0]
            \ \begin{pmatrix}3 & -4 & 8 & -15 \end{pmatrix}^T,
            \begin{pmatrix}4 & -4 & 5 & -12 \end{pmatrix}^T, 
            \begin{pmatrix}5 & -4 & 2 & -9 \end{pmatrix}^T, \linebreak[0]
            \begin{pmatrix}6 & -4 & -1 & -6 \end{pmatrix}^T
          \Big\}, \linebreak[0]
          \Big\{
            \begin{pmatrix}11 & -8 & 1 & -15 \end{pmatrix}^T, 
            \begin{pmatrix}17 & -12 & 0 & -21\end{pmatrix}^T, 
            \begin{pmatrix}7 & -4 & -4 & -3 \end{pmatrix}^T,  
            \begin{pmatrix}8 & -4 & -7 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^T 
          \Big \} $

\begin{align*}
    G(B) = 
      \Big\{& \begin{pmatrix}0 & 4 & -17 & 24 \end{pmatrix}^T,
             \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & -3 & 3 \end{pmatrix}^T,
             \begin{pmatrix}1 & -4 & 14 & -21 \end{pmatrix}^T, \\
       &     \begin{pmatrix}2 & -4 & 11 & -18 \end{pmatrix}^T, 
             \begin{pmatrix}3 & -4 & 8 & -15 \end{pmatrix}^T,
             \begin{pmatrix}4 & -4 & 5 & -12    \end{pmatrix}^T, \\
       &     \begin{pmatrix}5 & -4 & 2 & -9 \end{pmatrix}^T, 
             \begin{pmatrix}6 & -4 & -1 & -6 \end{pmatrix}^T
      \Big\}, \\
      \Big\{& 
             \begin{pmatrix}11 & -8 & 1 & -15 \end{pmatrix}^T, 
             \begin{pmatrix}17 & -12 & 0 & -21\end{pmatrix}^T, \\
            & \begin{pmatrix}7 & -4 & -4 & -3 \end{pmatrix}^T,  
             \begin{pmatrix}8 & -4 & -7 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^T 
      \Big \} 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Remove `\left` and `\right` which you do not need here and which prevent line breaking, then use something like `,\linebreak[0]` to allow line breaking after the comma between the matrices.